# Is it possible to hide a javascript confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, alert, prompt, confirm

I’m developing a Greasmonkey Script and I need to hide/suppress a confirm box. Here’s the code:

```
setInterval(function () {

        bla bla bla

        var Element = document.getElementById("id");
        Element.click();

        bla bla bla

    }, 2000); //Perform Actions x2000MS = 2.0Secs

}
```

When the script clicks on the element, the browser shows a confirm box that stops the script. How can I remove it?

I’ve tried with `window.confirm = function () {};` without success. What can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Essentially, when the `confirm` method is called, have it `return false`:

```
window.confirm = function() { return false; };
```

That will remove any default behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default alert function in the browser using

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

but I think generally alerts are meant for humans, and should not be overridden